# HCP and hexagonal primitive cell

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, crystallography, lattices, bravais-lattices

There are 14 types of Bravais lattices one of them is hexagonal which is just present as primitive cell ie the basis are at its corners , now when I read about hexagonal closed packing I came to know that it is a part of hexagonal system (from here [image]
) But it confused me that if it belongs to hexagonal system then it should be present in primitive cell form ,but there are atoms in the hexagonal closed packing prism which are present inside it. Why does this happen , can anyone clear my doubt?

Comment: Bravais lattice type does not tell you anything about where the atoms are. True, on the typical pictures they just sit at the corners and centered positions (if any), leading the students to believe there is a law to that effect. No, there isn't.

Comment: Green is a simple hexagonal Bravais lattice. Adding the orange atoms makes it a hexagonal lattice with a two-atom basis, resulting in a close-packed structure called hexagonal close packing (hcp).

Comment: You may do better than pasting a screen photo of your cell phone showing a part of a web page.  All the information about ad by your mobile carrier are not relevant to the question.  Instead, format your question, and add a accessible reference to the illustration and quote.